# Перекрытие слоя kml(geoxml) и активного слоя hotspot

Tags: yandex-maps-api

У меня на карте грузится kml с помощью

```
ymaps.geoXml.load(areal).then(function (res) {myMap.geoObjects.add(res.geoObjects);});
```

отдельно используется функционал активных областей:

```
        tileUrlTemplate = '/object_manager.php?x=%x&y=%y&z=%z';
        keyTemplate = 'jsonp_callback_%c';
        objSource = new ymaps.hotspot.ObjectSource(tileUrlTemplate, keyTemplate);
        hotspotLayer = new ymaps.hotspot.Layer(objSource, {cursor: 'help',hasBalloon:false,showEmptyBalloon: false,openBalloonOnClick: false});
```

Соответственно в тех местах карты, где kml пересекается с точками активного слоя, там не отрабатывается hotspotLayer.events.add('click'), даже курсор не меняется, потому что kml "загораживает" активный слой. Подскажите пожалуйста как побороть?

Answer (score 0):

В [документации Яндекса](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/hotspot.Layer.html) описание вашей ситуации есть: "*...если вы хотите наложить хотспотные объекты поверх площадных объектов, стоит задать хотспотному слою [zIndex](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/hotspot.Layer.html#hotspot.Layer__param-options.zIndex)=201. См. [map.pane.Manager](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/map.pane.Manager.html?lang=ru).*"

Если при этом вы зачем-то хотите перекрывать ещё и метки (точечные объекты), zIndex потребуется увеличивать минимум до 401.

Comment: спасибо большое!